# Read SMS in Android without using BroadCastReceiver

Tags: android, kotlin

I am implementing an Android application that should read SMS. I found so many solutions using BroadcastReceiver but I want to implement read SMS functionality without using BroadCastReceiver, is there any possibility to implement read SMS without using BroadCastReceiver.

Comment: I don't think without BroadCastReceiver you can read SMS, you can get more info from - https://medium.com/simform-engineering/sms-retriever-api-for-automatic-sms-verification-secure-android-otp-cafcb90f6b44

Comment: Unless this is registered as the default SMS application, just forget about it and save your time.